# How to scale a bunch of svg-elements to 100% of viewport

Tags: javascript, svg

meanwhile I've read a lot of sites about viewbox, viewports and svg scaling.
I have an svg-box, with variable size, depending on the browser-window.
Inside this, I display some elements like rects, lines texts etc.
These elements, or better the view is "zoomable" by using the mousewheel.

```
<h1>Editor:</h1>
<div id="content">
<svg id="drawing"
     title="Layouteditor"
     viewBox="0 0 500 300"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     version="2.0"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<g class="draggable preview" id="437" pointer-events="fill" transform="translate(150 50)">
  <rect fill="none" x="80" y="100" width="41" height="41"></rect>
  <line class="CDC300" fill="none" x1="140" y1="120" x2="121" y2="120" />
  <text class="CDC300" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="30px" fill="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="131">T</text>
  <text class="CDC400" id="20010" text-anchor="end" x="75" y="125">=HTC1+HSP1</text>
  <circle class="insertpoint" cx="140" cy="120" r="3" />
  <circle class="pin" cx="140" cy="120" r="2" />
</g>
<g id="a123" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
  <line class="hotwater graphic" id="g123" x1="100" y1="120" x2="200" y2="120"></line>
</g> 
</svg>
</div>
```

the scripts:

```
var svgDrawing = document.getElementById('drawing');
var viewbox = svgDrawing.viewBox.baseVal;

function zoomInOut(evt) {
    if (evt.deltaY > 1) {
        viewbox.width += 10;
        viewbox.height += 10;
    } else {
        viewbox.width -= 10;
        viewbox.height -= 10;
    }
}

function zoomFull(evt){
    console.log("Zoom 100%");
  //here, the zoom should be set to 100% of the drawing
  //###################################################
  //###################################################
  //###################################################
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("document ready");
    svgDrawing.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight - 200);
    svgDrawing.addEventListener('wheel', e => zoomInOut(e));
    svgDrawing.addEventListener('dblclick', e=>zoomFull(e));
})
```

[Here, it is on codepen](https://codepen.io/Telefisch/pen/jOPNwyz)

now, I'd like to add a "fullZoom"-function.
For this, I need to get the outer dimensions of all nested elements, I think. So perhaps like a boundingBox over all elements. And here, you come into the game. I am totally confused meanwhile.

Thank you,
Carsten

Comment: Check out this image - i.stack.imgur.com/RgDPz.png and the updated answer and demo - codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/NWqWEOw - you can easily add another point for the top left and use that in the viewbox to set the x and y to non-zero values so that the elements are shown as largely as possible inside the svg viewbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you realize but your SVG is also changing size (specifically its width as you scroll)? (I added a blue border to the `<div/>` and black border to the `<svg/>`)

On load:

[image]

On scroll-in:

[image]

This is because you only fix the height on document load. If you ifx the width too, this problem goes away: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/poJzWEN

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("document ready");
    svgDrawing.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight - 200);
    svgDrawing.setAttribute("width", 1.5 * (window.innerHeight - 200));
    svgDrawing.addEventListener('wheel', e => zoomInOut(e));
    svgDrawing.addEventListener('dblclick', e=>zoomFull(e));
})
```

Then we can scroll without "growing" our width.

Is your desired outcome on double-click something like this:

i.e. any elements within as close to the edge of the svg as allows?

[image]

**UPDATE**

If you want to just return to original zoom, assuming you created the SVG with the original zoom first set up (hard-coded) etc. in the viewport etc.? Then you can simply save this original value and reset it when the user double clicks?

Demo: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/poJzWEN?editors=1010

JS:

```
const svgDrawing = document.getElementById('drawing');
// console.log(svgDrawing.currentTranslate);
let viewbox = svgDrawing.viewBox.baseVal;
const original_w = viewbox.width;
const original_h = viewbox.height;
const w_h_ratio = 2;
const g = document.getElementById('437'); 
console.log(g.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix);
var point = svgDrawing.createSVGPoint();

function zoomEvent(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (evt.deltaY > 1) {
    zoomInOut(-1, 10);
  } else {
    zoomInOut(+1, 10);
  }
}

function zoomInOut(direction, stepSize) {
  if (direction > 0) {
    viewbox.width -= w_h_ratio * stepSize;
    viewbox.height -= stepSize;
  } else {
    viewbox.width += w_h_ratio * stepSize;
    viewbox.height += stepSize;
  }
}

function zoomFull(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  viewbox.width = original_w;
  viewbox.height = original_h;
  console.log("Zoom 100%");    
}

function elementIsInside(el, box){
  var result = false;
  el_rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  point.x = el_rect.x;
  point.y = el_rect.y;
  point.width = el_rect.width;
  point.height = el_rect.height; 
  var invertedSVGMatrix = el.getScreenCTM().inverse();
  var p = point.matrixTransform(invertedSVGMatrix);

  box_rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (el_rect.left >= box_rect.left &&
      el_rect.right <= box_rect.right &&
      el_rect.bottom <= box_rect.bottom &&
      el_rect.top >= box_rect.top){
    result = true;
  } else {
    result = false;
  }
  // console.log("result_" + el.tagName, result)
  return result;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("document ready");
  svgDrawing.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight - 200);
  svgDrawing.setAttribute("width", w_h_ratio * (window.innerHeight - 200));
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('wheel', e => zoomEvent(e));
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('dblclick', e=>zoomFull(e));
})
```

**UPDATE**

I also tried to do the other idea (to get the max zoom that still shows all elements on-screen: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/NWqWEOw and I believe I have done it.

I added a red circle on the screen to show that we maximized the viewport to the maximum possible. i.e.:

[image]

OR

[image]

Wherever we move the elements around, the double-click event will fire the function that loops through the elements and saves the largest bottom and right points of the boundary boxes each element has and then alters the zoom port to that.

JS:

```
const svgDrawing = document.getElementById('drawing');
// console.log(svgDrawing.currentTranslate);
let viewbox = svgDrawing.viewBox.baseVal;
let original_w = viewbox.width;
let original_h = viewbox.height;
let w_h_ratio = 2;
const g = document.getElementById('437'); 
console.log(g.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix);
// const extra = document.getElementById('example'); 
// console.log(extra.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix);
const b_box = document.getElementById('bounding_box');
const b_box_max = {right: 0, bottom: 0};
var point = svgDrawing.createSVGPoint();

function zoomEvent(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (evt.deltaY > 1) {
    zoomInOut(-1, 10);
  } else {
    zoomInOut(+1, 10);
  }
}

function zoomInOut(direction, stepSize) {
  if (direction > 0) {
    viewbox.width -= w_h_ratio * stepSize;
    viewbox.height -= stepSize;
  } else {
    viewbox.width += w_h_ratio * stepSize;
    viewbox.height += stepSize;
  }
}

function zoomToSize(width, height) {
  viewbox.width = width;
  viewbox.height = height;
}

function zoomFull(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  viewbox.width = original_w;
  viewbox.height = original_h;
  console.log("Zoom 100%");
  const elements = [...svgDrawing.childNodes];
  console.log("elements", elements);
  var inside = true;
  for (let el of elements){            
    if (el.nodeName == "#text"){
      //this is not a real node
    } else if (elementIsInside(el, svgDrawing)){
      inside = true;
    } else {
      inside = false;
    }
  }
  // var dir = inside ? +1 : -1;
  // zoomInOut(dir, (100/(10**i)));
  zoomToSize(b_box_max.right,b_box_max.bottom);
}

function elementIsInside(el, box){
  var result = false;
  el_rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  point.x = el_rect.right;
  point.y = el_rect.bottom;
  var invertedSVGMatrix = el.getScreenCTM().inverse();
  var p = point.matrixTransform(invertedSVGMatrix);
  let trans = el.transform.baseVal;
  if (trans.length > 0){
    const matrix = trans.consolidate().matrix;
    p.x += matrix.e;
    p.y += matrix.f;
  }
  if (p.x > b_box_max.right){
    b_box.setAttribute('cx', p.x);
    b_box_max.right = p.x;
    b_box.setAttribute('cx', p.x);
  }
  if (p.y > b_box_max.bottom){
    b_box.setAttribute('cy', p.y);
    b_box_max.bottom = p.y;
    b_box.setAttribute('cy', p.y);
  }
  b_box.setAttribute('r', 5);  

  console.log(p.x, p.y);
  console.log(b_box_max.right,b_box_max.bottom);
  box_rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (el_rect.left >= box_rect.left &&
      el_rect.right <= box_rect.right &&
      el_rect.bottom <= box_rect.bottom &&
      el_rect.top >= box_rect.top){
    result = true;
  } else {
    result = false;
  }
  // console.log("result_" + el.tagName, result)
  return result;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("document ready");
  resizeSVG();
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('wheel', e => zoomEvent(e));
  svgDrawing.addEventListener('dblclick', e=>zoomFull(e));
})

$(window).resize(function() {
  console.log($(window).width(), $(window).height());
  // console.log(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   resizeSVG();
});

function resizeSVG(){
  if ((window.innerWidth - 40) / w_h_ratio > (window.innerHeight - 120)){
    svgDrawing.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight - 120);
    svgDrawing.setAttribute("width", w_h_ratio * (window.innerHeight - 120));
  } else{
    svgDrawing.setAttribute("height", (window.innerWidth - 40) / w_h_ratio);
    svgDrawing.setAttribute("width", (window.innerWidth - 40));
  }
  viewbox = svgDrawing.viewBox.baseVal;
  original_w = viewbox.width;
  original_h = viewbox.height;
  w_h_ratio = 2;
}
```

Most important lines:

```
function zoomFull(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  viewbox.width = original_w;
  viewbox.height = original_h;
  console.log("Zoom 100%");
  const elements = [...svgDrawing.childNodes];
  console.log("elements", elements);
  var inside = true;
  for (let el of elements){            
    if (el.nodeName == "#text"){
      //this is not a real node
    } else if (elementIsInside(el, svgDrawing)){
      inside = true;
    } else {
      inside = false;
    }
  }
  zoomToSize(b_box_max.right,b_box_max.bottom);
}
```

Loop through all children elements in the svg and call the function `elementIsInside()`:

```
function elementIsInside(el, box){
  var result = false;
  el_rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  point.x = el_rect.right;
  point.y = el_rect.bottom;
  var invertedSVGMatrix = el.getScreenCTM().inverse();
  var p = point.matrixTransform(invertedSVGMatrix);
  let trans = el.transform.baseVal;
  if (trans.length > 0){
    const matrix = trans.consolidate().matrix;
    p.x += matrix.e;
    p.y += matrix.f;
  }
  if (p.x > b_box_max.right){
    b_box.setAttribute('cx', p.x);
    b_box_max.right = p.x;
    b_box.setAttribute('cx', p.x);
  }
  if (p.y > b_box_max.bottom){
    b_box.setAttribute('cy', p.y);
    b_box_max.bottom = p.y;
    b_box.setAttribute('cy', p.y);
  }
  b_box.setAttribute('r', 5);  

  console.log(p.x, p.y);
  console.log(b_box_max.right,b_box_max.bottom);
  box_rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (el_rect.left >= box_rect.left &&
      el_rect.right <= box_rect.right &&
      el_rect.bottom <= box_rect.bottom &&
      el_rect.top >= box_rect.top){
    result = true;
  } else {
    result = false;
  }
  // console.log("result_" + el.tagName, result)
  return result;
}
```

Translate bounding client rect from page coordinates to svg coordinates.

If the element has a transformation (like the group elements often do - such as `transform="translate(200, 250)"`, then we also add these (matrix.e and matrix.f) onto our points. If the right is larger than the currently saved maximum right, then replace it, same for the bottom. Move the circle to this point to highlight.

**UPDATE**

https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/NWqWEOw

You can also add a top left minimum point (shown here in green):

[image]

This comes from the following function, making a second point, p2:

```
function elementIsInside(el, box){
  var result = false;
  el_rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  point.x = el_rect.right;
  point.y = el_rect.bottom;
  var invertedSVGMatrix = el.getScreenCTM().inverse();
  var p = point.matrixTransform(invertedSVGMatrix);
  point.x = el_rect.left;
  point.y = el_rect.top;
  var p2 = point.matrixTransform(invertedSVGMatrix);
  let trans = el.transform.baseVal;
  if (trans.length > 0){
    const matrix = trans.consolidate().matrix;
    p.x += matrix.e;
    p.y += matrix.f;
    p2.x += matrix.e;
    p2.y += matrix.f;
  }
  if (p.x > b_box_max.right){
    b_box_br.setAttribute('cx', p.x);
    b_box_max.right = p.x;
  }
  if (p.y > b_box_max.bottom){
    b_box_br.setAttribute('cy', p.y);
    b_box_max.bottom = p.y;
  }
  b_box_br.setAttribute('r', 5); 

  if (p2.x < b_box_max.left){
    b_box_tl.setAttribute('cx', p2.x);
    b_box_max.left = p2.x;
  }
  if (p2.y < b_box_max.top){
    b_box_tl.setAttribute('cy', p2.y);
    b_box_max.top = p2.y;
  }
  b_box_tl.setAttribute('r', 5); 

  b_box_max.width = b_box_max.right - b_box_max.left;
  b_box_max.height = b_box_max.bottom - b_box_max.top;

  console.log(p2.x, p2.y, p.x, p.y);
  console.log(b_box_max.right,b_box_max.bottom);
  box_rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (el_rect.left >= box_rect.left &&
      el_rect.right <= box_rect.right &&
      el_rect.bottom <= box_rect.bottom &&
      el_rect.top >= box_rect.top){
    result = true;
  } else {
    result = false;
  }
  // console.log("result_" + el.tagName, result)
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, you are right, in my app, the width is fix to 100% and I could PAN inside the drawing to move the content around. My question is, if a user has drawn something outside the viewport or has moved the drawing in zoomed mode so there is only part of it visible, I want to scale and move the viewport to 100% of the drawing. I don't know how to better explain it.  ...imagine you zoomed to the black point, right of the box, so the viewport is filled with it. Now you doubleclick and get a view, similar to the first picture of your post.

Comment: I think I need something like selecting all elements inside the svgDrawing and then get their `getBoundingClientRect()` to calculate the dimensions and the x/y coordinates.

Comment: Does this give you the desired behaviour? https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/poJzWEN?editors=1010

Comment: Hi Alex, If I understood your code, you declare the width and height of the viewbox as a constant. My goal is to find the boundings of all elements to calculate the needed viewbox. It can be very different to the viewbox on pageload and depends on the content, that was drawn by the user. Imagine you set the y-value of your extrabox to 200, than you should see it on 100% zoom.

Comment: Ahh ok, maybe I have an idea how to do it. Loop through every bounding rect and ensure the viewport is large enough to see all bottom right corners. I’ll try to do that later today.

Comment: should be done - https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/NWqWEOw

Comment: Hi Alex, I still have some problems, so first, can you describe what happens here: const elements = [...svgDrawing.childNodes]; - I know what this does but how does this work with the three dots and which kind of objects are in elements after that?

Then I have another question. You always set 0,0 as the fix position for the viewbox. This isn't always the truth, so how can I calculate the x and y minimum-position of the elements. I tried hundrets of approaches but all failed. Meanwhile, I'm totally confused.

Comment: [... args] is the spread operator - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax available since 2015 (ES6) it just unpacks the elements of the list/iterable into the array.

Comment: Check out this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgDPz.png and the updated answer and demo - https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/NWqWEOw - you can easily add another point for the top left and use that in the viewbox to set the x and y to non-zero values so that the elements are shown as largely as possible inside the svg viewbox.

Comment: Hi Alex, first of all, thanks for your help and for your patience. This week, I‘m on vacation so I will get back for this issue next week.